# Mysql query to select records from previous minute

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, average

I have a mysql database where a new record is added about every 10 seconds. I need to run a query that returns the average of the records from the previous minute. The following returns a partial average of the previous minute and a partial average of the current minute.

```
SELECT Avg(Irms) AS Irms, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS datetime
FROM power
WHERE datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 121 MINUTE GROUP BY MINUTE(datetime)
```

So for example assuming NOW() = 19:23:31 it will return the average of the last 3 records of the previous minute and the average of the first three records of the current minute.

How do I structure my query statement to ensure that it returns the average of all the records from the previous minute only? For example, if NOW() = 19:23:31 it will return the average of the six records entered from 19:22:00 to 19:22:59.

Thanks. - Baobab

Comment: Can you elaborate on the requirement for 3 records from the past minute and 3 from the current minute?  Is this just an example, or do you always want this number of records?

Comment: that's an example. I only want it to average the records from the  previous minute. But it averages the records from within the last minute so I get back two averages, one for the last portion of the previous minute and one for the first portion of the current minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(Irms) AS Irms, DATE_FORMAT(DATETIME, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS DATETIME
FROM POWER
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATETIME, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```